# R Regexp - extract number with 5 digits

Tags: regex, r

i have a string `a` like this one:

> stundenwerte_FF_00691_19260101_20131231_hist.zip

and would like to extract the 5-digit number "00691" from it.

I tried using `gregexpr` and `regmatches` as well as `stringr::str_extract`
but couldn't figute out the right rexexp.
I came as far as:

> gregexpr("[:digits{5}:]",a)

Which should return 5-digit-numbers and i dont understand how to fix it.
This does not work propperly :(

```
m <- gregexpr("[:digits{5}:]",a)
regmatches(a,m)
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: This (site)[http://regex101.com/] can help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could simply use `sub` to grab the digits, IMO `regmatches` is not necessary for this simple case.

```
x <- 'stundenwerte_FF_00691_19260101_20131231_hist.zip'
sub('\\D*(\\d{5}).*', '\\1', x)
# [1] "00691"
```

**Edit:** If you have other strings that contain digits in front, you would slightly modify the expression.

```
sub('.*_(\\d{5})_.*', '\\1', x)
```

Comment: Note that this regexp assumes that no digits appear prior to the `00691`.

Comment: Very true, this is based off the given string in which if OPs intention was to match the 5 digits between `_` ... `_` I would of wrote the answer you supplied.

Comment: What if you wanted numbers between 5 and 7 digits?

Answer (score 6):

**1) sub**

```
sub(".*_(\\d{5})_.*", "\\1", x)
## [1] "00691"
```

**2) gsubfn::strapplyc**  The regexp can be slightly simplified if we use `strapplyc`:

```
library(gsubfn)

strapplyc(x, "_(\\d{5})_", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "00691"
```

**3) strsplit**  If we know that it is the third field:

```
read.table(text = x, sep = "_", colClasses = "character")$V3
## [1] "00691"
```

**3a)** or

```
strsplit(x, "_")[[1]][3]
## [1] "00691"
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try the below regex which uses negative lookaround assertions. We can't use word boundaries here like `\\b\\d{5}\\b` because the preceding  and the following character `_` comes under `\w`

```
> x <- "stundenwerte_FF_00691_19260101_20131231_hist.zip"
> m <- regexpr("(?<!\\d)\\d{5}(?!\\d)", x, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(x, m)
[1] "00691"
> m <- gregexpr("(?<!\\d)\\d{5}(?!\\d)", x, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(x, m)[[1]]
[1] "00691"
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!\\d)` Negative lookbehind asserts that what precedes the match would be any but not a digit.
- `\\d{5}` Match exactly 5 digits.
- `(?!\\d)` Negative lookahead asserts that the character following the match would be any but not a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Let string be:

```
ss ="stundenwerte_FF_00691_19260101_20131231_hist.zip"
```

You can split the string and unlist the substrings:

```
ll = unlist(strsplit(ss,'_'))
```

Then get indexes of substrings set to TRUE if they are 5 characters long:

```
idx = sapply(ll, nchar)==5
```

And get the ones which are 5 characters long:

```
ll[idx]
[1] "00691"
```